# Windows 8 compatibility with development tools.

Tags: eclipse, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-8

My boss just asked me about Windows 8. He wants to get me a new laptop. And is still confused about the os.

Can VS2010 be installed on windows 8? because VS2012 can be installed in windows 7.
How about like eclipse java android? Can they run in windows 8?

Comment: You can't buy a laptop yet with Windows 8, because it isn't released yet. And when it is, you'll want to get one with a touch screen.

Comment: My boss say he wants to buy it when the windows 8 is released. Actually I dont care about the visual studio. I assume the visual studio can run. I just wondering about the eclipse. :D

Comment: If you don't care about visual studio, why is that the main thing in your question?

Answer (score 3):

the visual studio 2012 is more recommended in windows 8 in order to install certain sdk's like windows phone 8 sdk .. so it should work even more smooth in windows 8 
eclipse and java also work fine ... most of the application that works with win 7 will work with win 8 without a problem i didn't find any issue tell now only some drive that wasn't installed correctly and the windows search for the drive for me and install it from the device manager .. the only issue that i can't solve it tell now the 2 finger scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft website, VS 2012 is compatible with Windows 8 :

http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/compatibility

I read [some returns](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/819251/) about Eclipse, that's not possible (or not basically possible) to run it on Windows 8 right now, but I guess it will be soon, when Windows 8 will be released...

Comment: saw a colleagues using eclipse days ago, and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 is just another OS by MICROSOFT where they have changed the architecture of the Operating System. All those software that were compatible on previous version on Windows will be working fine in windows 8. Windows 8 has apps as the new thing in it.

It does not matter you buy a laptop with or without windows 8. its an operating system which you can install on any machine provided it has the basic requirements of windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

I just installed windows 8, visual studio 2012, eclipse, java and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

you can use either VS 2012 or VS 2010 in Windows 8. VS 2012 is compatible only in Windows8.

A touch screen is not a must to use Windows 8 but it is recommended for the best user experience.